# Как считать данные из удаленной БД в DataFrame?

Tags: python, база-данных, sql-server, pandas, anaconda

Вот скрипт, позволяющий обратиться к БД. K ней нужно подключиться с помощью строки соединения:

```
import pyodbc

driver = 'DRIVER={SQL Server}'
server = 'SERVER=111.000.00.00'
port = 'PORT=1433'
DB = 'DATABASE=testdb'
user = 'UID=me'
pw = 'PWD=pass'
conn_str = ';'.join([driver, server, port, DB, user, pw])

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Как нужную таблицу `testtable` из `testdb` скопировать в DataFrame?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.read_sql.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [pd.read_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html).

Пример:

```
import mssql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# pyodbc
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@mydsn')

# pymssql
# engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://scott:tiger@hostname:port/dbname')

qry = """select * from testtable"""
df = pd.read_sql(qry, engine)
```

---

**UPDATE:** самое сложное здесь это указать правильное значение для `connection string` при создании `engine`.

[Альтернативный вариант](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#hostname-connections):

```
import urllib
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=dagger;DATABASE=test;UID=user;PWD=password")

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
```