# pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC]

Tags: python, sql

консоль выдает такую ошибку:
  File "python.py", line 3, in 
    conn_str = pyodbc.connect(
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник 
данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Cам код:

```
import pyodbc

conn_str = (
r'Driver={SQL Serever};'
r'Server=127.0.0.1;'
r'Database=test1;'
)

db = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cr = db.cu
```

Comment: [связанный вопрос ...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1113137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b2-dataframe)